# Android: download and save image in SD. Error when i try open file before writing finished

Tags: android, webview, file-exists

I'm trying to download and save a list of images from the internet to the SD card in the background with an `AsyncTask`, this work fine.

On the other hand, in the main code, I would check if image exists on the SD card or not. If it exists, then load the image locally, and if not load the URL image.

The problem appears when the file image exists but the writing is not completed. In this case the webview loads a white page.

I've tried this, but the problem is I don't know the file size, and the images are different sizes.

```
if(file.exists() && file.length() > 18000){
    //Load SD file
}
else{
    //Load url
}
```

Is there any way of knowing whether the file writing is completed?

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is.

try this

```
final int giveUpTimeout = 5;
new Timer().schedule( new TimerTask() {
           public void run() {
              try{
                  int cc = giveUpTimeout;
                  while ( cc > 0 ) {
                      sleep(1000);   // wait 1 sec
                      cc --;
                      if ( file.exists() && file.lenght()>0 ) {
                           ... 
                          // LOAD sd FILE    
                          return ; // should exit
                          }
                      }
                  //  your else           
                  ... LOAD URL
                  }
              catch ( Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
          }
      },
      0);
```

bjarn =]

Comment: tanks pirataJoe, but this code introduce a time delay. I want to directly load the url if the writing on the sd is not complete.

Comment: ok mgabal, but the solution is there, somewhere ;). you asked for a way to check if file is complete and i put it there somewhere a "file.canWrite". Enjoy that. ciao

Comment: and AFAIK, there is no way to make what you ask without a delay and a timer.

Comment: "file.canWrite()" not working. I think this method only indicates whether you have write permissions on the file (always is true, even if the file is not complete)

Comment: having knowledge of the problem: if you know the larger and the lower file size you expect, this is a "worst case" approach. you only have to know the larger file size to tweak your code, so that (f.e)  a 2-second delay may give you the certainty of 90% of the file is complete. so to me the solution is file.lenght()>0 ; sleep( ESTIMATED_DELAY );